# code to used to test in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I need to pass the service call test using jasmine.js

the code below is my angular.js service call:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

  app.controller('Myctrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")

       .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response.records;});

 });
```

How to pass the unit test using jasmine.js? I tried this but it wasn't successful:

```
describe('Myctrl', function() {

   var $httpBackend, scope, createController, authRequestHandler;

   // Set up the module  
   beforeEach(module('myApp'));

      alert("Hello there!");

    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
     // Set up the mock http service responses
        alert("Hello there!");
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

     // backend definition common for all tests
    alert("Hello there!");
     authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.whenGET('GET', 'http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php')
                            .respond(true);

     // Get hold of a scope (i.e. the root scope)

     $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope'); 

     // The $controller service is used to create instances of controllers
     var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');


     createController = function() {

       return $controller('Myctrl', {'$scope' : scope});

     };

   })



);
/*
  afterEach(function () {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });
*/


  it('should fetch authentication token', function() {
       //create expectation   
     $httpBackend.expectGET('GET','http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php')
     var controller = createController()
     $httpBackend.flush();
     expect(scope.names).toBeTruthy(true); 

   });


});
```

Comment: i edited the post and posted the code that i have tried so far

Comment: Tried to remove all the statements repeating the same thing. Hopefully it's more clear now

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
describe('Myctrl', function() {
  var $httpBackend, $scope, authRequestHandler, createController, url;
  $httpBackend = void 0;
  $scope = void 0;
  createController = void 0;
  authRequestHandler = void 0;
  url = void 0;
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  alert('Hello there!');
  beforeEach(inject(function($injector, $controller, $rootscope) {
    var controllerService;
    alert('Hello there!');
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    alert('Hello there!');
    url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php';
    $scope = $rootscope.$new();
    controllerService = $controller;
    createController = function() {
      return controllerService('Myctrl', {
        '$scope': $scope
      });
    };
  }));

  /*
    afterEach(function () {
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });
   */
  it('should fetch authentication token', function() {
    $httpBackend.whenGET(url).respond();
    $httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond();
    $httpBackend.flush();
    createController();
    expect($scope.names).toBeTruthy(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: stll um getting error saying  "unknown provider  : $controllerprovider"

Answer (score 0):

Let's explain it all :

```
// group tests of the same component with 'describe'
describe( "MyCtrl", function () {

    // where you put the reference of the controller
    var myctrl;
    // where you put the reference of the scope
    var $scope;
    // where you put the reference of httpBackend which simulate http request/response
    var httpBackend;

    // fake data 
    var data = { records: "Hello I am the server" };

    // function executed BEFORE each test ("it")
    beforeEach( function () {

        // load you module
        module( "myApp" );

        // use the injector to get referencies
        inject( function ( $injector ) {
            // get $controller which allows you to generate a controller and to inject its dependencies
            var $controller = $injector.get( "$controller" );
            // get $rootScope which allows you to generate a new scope empty
            var $rootScope = $injector.get( "$httpBackend" );
            // get httpBackend
            httpBackend = $injector.get( "$httpBackend" );

            // create a fake scope and store it in your reference
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            // inject dependencies in your controller and get the reference
            myctrl = $controller( "MyCtrl", {
                $scope: $scope,
                $http: httpBackend
            });

            // define what httpBackend do
            httpBackend.whenGET( "http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php" ).respond( data );
        });
    });

    // function executed AFTER each test ("it")
    afterEach( function () {
        // nothing here, you may even remove this "afterEach", it's just for the exemple
    });

    // your first test
    it( "GET", function () {
        // here your scope.names should be empty
        expect( $scope.names ).toBeUndefined();

        // resole the request of httpBackend
        httpBackend.flush();

        // now your scope.names should be the fake data.records
        expect( $scope.names ).toEqual( data.records );
    });
});
```

I didn't test it, it may contain some errors, but the method is here. It's up to you now ;)